# Set text input cursor position terminal C++

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, terminal

I've Googled for a while but cannot find a way to set the cursor position for text input in OS X's terminal.

I've found many answers using `<windows.h>` for Microsoft computers but nothing for OS X. Can anybody point me to some literature?

**I simply want to use the `placeCursor` method in `<windows.h>` on a Mac.**

Thank you

Comment: `OS X` is obviously not the same as windows, so using `<windows.h>` probably won't do you much good even if you could use `placecursor`. What exactly are you trying to do in Terminal that requires this?

Comment: You probably want to use [ncurses](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/ncurses.3x.html). It's basically a text windowing system.